# Deleting elements from numpy array is altering original list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, del

I have a function which basically looks like this:

```
def calculatRatioList(self, inputList=None, listIndex=None):
    divisorArray = np.reshape(np.asarray(inputList[listIndex]), (-1))
    dividendArray = inputList
    ratioList = []
    # take element from inputList which will be the dividend
    for divisorIndex in range(len(divisorArray)):
        columnList = []
        del dividendArray[listIndex]
        for dividend_column in range(len(dividendArray)):
            quotient = 0
            dividend = np.asarray(dividendArray)[dividend_column][divisorIndex]
            divisor = float(divisorArray[divisorIndex])
            try:
                quotient = dividend / divisor
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                quotient = 0
            columnList.append(quotient)
        ratioList.append(columnList)
    return ratioList
```

I hope one can grasp the idea by just looking in the code above. Anyway, the idea briefly introduced is: take an array which is two dimensional (n,5), wherein n is any number. The `listIndex` parameter is the one representing the row, which shall be taken to the divisorArray, the dividendArray shall take the remaining elements from the inputList.

In order to delete the elements and go by like `del dividendArray[listIndex]`it always alters my inputList in the `main.py` either.

Can someone explain what this behaviour is good for? It annoys me and right now it seems more like a bug than something made with intuition.

What is a convenient way to delete elements in a numpy array, **without going by a list**.

I go by an input which looks like:
`inputList = [[a11, a12, a13, a14], [a21, a22, a23, a24], [a31, a32, a33, a34], [a41, a42, a43, a44]]`

this input is assigned to dividendArray. After the line
`del dividendArray[listIndex]`
one can find
`inputList = [[a11, a12, a13, a14], [a21, a22, a23, a24], [a31, a32, a33, a34]]`

Comment: I'm not following what you code is doing, but ***lists are mutable***.  If you don't want to mutate the original list, make a copy of it in your function and operate on that.

Comment: As for why that is good: copying takes time and memory. If you don't need to keep the original list it would be a waste if you couldn't stop the code from copying.

Comment: thanks for your reply, of course they are mutable. but why are they also altering as I operate on a array which were just created by the list. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77502891/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I'm surprised `del dividendArray[listIndex]` doesn't raise _"ValueError: cannot delete array elements"_.

Comment: I don't expect  `del dividendArray[listIndex]` to do anything to the array. `del` does no act on arrays like it does on list.

Comment: you guys were right, I corrected it in this edit now. thanks!

Comment: So now `dividendArray` _is_ the original list. You already know that lists are mutable, so you shouldn't be surprised that mutating `dividendArray` inside the function mutates the list everywhere!

Comment: When I first saw this question, you had `dividendArray = np.asarray(inputList)`.  When I went to test it, it's now `dividendArray = inputList`.  Changing the original list is obvious.  Using `dividendArray =inputList[:]` corrects that (making a top level copy of the nested list).

Comment: There is a `np.delete` function that makes a new array each time.  It's not efficient to use that in a loop.  In fact, it isn't efficient to simply substitute arrays for lists.  Use arrays as intended (by the docs), not as a drop in substitute for lists.

Comment: my bad sorry for wasting your time and thanks for helping me even though. I always have seen arrays as an easy way to perform mathematical operations and list to give values a structure. therefore gathering values is a list job and making the calculation is an array job to me. Anyway, thank you already for showing me the difference of  ```a = inputList``` and ```a = inputList[:]```
 - I thought both were equal